# Using data from XML file in HTML Document

Tags: javascript, html, xml, youtube-api, xmldom

As the title suggests I would like to be able to use data from a XML file in a HTML page. Let me explain what the page is trying to do in order to help explain what I need help with..

The HTML page when complete will go to the YouTube servers with a search query and retrieve a XML file that is generated from the search with up to date information.
Then the page will look into the XML file given, and find the `<yt:videoid>` node, and transfer the string to the HTML file.
Then the HTML file can use the string (probably in javascript) to make the embed video code.

The resulting page will therefore always have the latest video due to the search query.

So far I have found the link to get the XML file (below) and had a look at the XML
(Link:  https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=inthegamesroom&orderby=published&prettyprint=true&start-index=1&max-results=1&v=2)

I found out that the information I want is in a node called `<yt:videoid>` which is under `<media:group>` which is under `<feed>`

After doing some research online (as I am not a javascript programmer, I only have a basic knowledge, I found that you can use XML DOM to read and adapt XML files from within an HTML page. But the problem with XML DOM code is that it requires the XML file to be hosted on the actual server itself, which it is obviously not - as it's on youtube.

Does anyone know a way I could just read the  data and put it into a javascript variable? I don't necessarily want you to spend ages writing some code, but at least hope you can lead me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot in advanced,

Ant.

PS, Please bear in mind I am not a JS or HTML programmer.. I only know the basics, and if I have done anything wrong in this post please let me know as this is a first for me on stackoverflow.

Comment: You'll have to use some php and ajax and it's gonna be messy.

Comment: @PitaJ Why will he have to use PHP?

Comment: @LeeTaylor He can't really do it without php. He has to get information from a file an another server

Comment: @PitaJ So PHP is the only server side technology?

Comment: ... then any active framework would do, no? Ruby on Rails, ASP.NET, Node.js, etc.... the list could go on.

Comment: @LeeYaylor - I use PHP and nothing else, so I suggested PHP. Is there a problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do anything browser side to get the XML or parse it.

Youtube's API is public and allows anyone (?) to query it, meaning you just need a simple ajax call to get the xml file. With some additional jQuery (or any other library) you can then extract the id of the video:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // request xml data
    jQuery.ajax('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=inthegamesroom&orderby=published&prettyprint=true&start-index=1&max-results=1&v=2',{
        dataType:'xml',
        success: function(data,status, xhr ) {
           // process response
           var $_d =$(data);

           var videoTag = $_d.find('yt\\:videoid'); // doesn't seem to work
           var videoTag = $_d.find('videoid'); // works
           var videoId = videoTag.text();

           // do the embedding
           embedYT(videoId);
        }
    });

   // a simple way to embed a youtube player in a page
   function embedYT(id) {
        jQuery(document.body).append("<iframe class='youtube-player' type='text/html' width='640' height='385' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+id+" frameborder='0'></iframe>")
   }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAffm/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't used ajax before though, it looks like similar to a function (of some sort) in javascript.. so do I need to call it to be used withing jQuery?

Comment: Or does it run the function, and then I just need to use the videoId variable?

Comment: `$` in this case refers to jQuery (might as well use `jQuery.ajax()`).

Comment: The above code will query for the xml from the given address. When the file is returned the `success` function will run automatically and retrieve the value if the video id. You can then do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: It's weird.. I see it working in the jsFiddle link but its not working for me in html code.. I'm placing it within `<script src=jquery.js> ... </script>` and have jquery.js in the same folder.. is this a lack of something on windows, or shall I move it to my Linux webhost?

Comment: you can't place anything inside a script tag that links to an external file. Add another script tag and place your code inside that one.

Comment: Ahh ok, It's all working now apart from the embed is just making a outline.. I should be able to sort this out myself now, thanks for your help! (I'll bump if something goes horrifically wrong :P)

Comment: All working fine, Just wondering how I could (if possible) make this x3 on a website? So it loads up the 3 latest videos.. I've tried the long way of duplicating the functions and changing variable names, but this didn't work.. Do any of the commands not work when called twice?

Comment: You can change the value of the query variable `max_results` to 3, which will then return 3 videos. `videoTag` will then contain an array of elements each containing the id of the video.

Comment: In my mind right now, you are a genius :D Last thing now, promise! How can I make `jQuery(document.body)` work in a table, because it's not formatting correctly - is there a way to make it be in the place the function is called?

Comment: You can place it pretty much wherever you want. Just replace `document.body` with the element you want to insert the video in. see the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) on how to do this.

Comment: It now won't append anything, Did I do something wrong with the array? [pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/hu1sU0jA) - Sorry cant post code in comments.. I presumed this would work?

Comment: It doesn't append anything because you moved `embedYT` outside of the ajax call. You will only know the id's of the videos after a successful query so it needs to be inside the `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

Example php code:

```
// content of example.php
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=inthegamesroom&orderby=published&prettyprint=true&start-index=1&max-results=1&v=2');
foreach( $xml->children() as $child) {
    if($child->getName() == 'yt:videoid'){
        echo $child->asXML();
    }
}

?>
```

Example jQuery code:

```
var ytUrlThing;
$.post('example.php', function(data) { ytUrlThing = data; });
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm guessing I make a PHP page then, and then add the jQuery code to my HTML file which will then use the PHP script to obtain the data?

Comment: @th3ant yes. Put the php in it's own file and then put the ajax in your page where you need the youtube data.

Comment: Sorry being a bit on a noob here.. I appreciate the help.. Ajax? I thought you said it was jquery :S